# WSO2 API Manager - displaying host name rather IP in UI

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We deployed wso2am in a server and currently we can use host name to access it, but when I log on wso2am store to subscribe a API, It still display its IP rather than hostname in the UI (overview part), like:

URLs:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8280/pizzashack/1.0.0
https://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8243/pizzashack/1.0.0
```

so  any one can tell me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to edit the `APIEndpointURL` property in `AM_HOME/repository/conf/api-manager.xml` file. Mine looks as follows after editing.

```
<APIEndpointURL>http://apim.example.org:${http.nio.port},https://apim.example.org:${https.nio.port}</APIEndpointURL>
```

This is in addition to specifying `<HostName>` and `<MgtHostName>` in `AM_HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I can see the hostname in the UI

Comment: I have done all the necessary changes mentioned in this answer.Now I can see proper URLs in the UI. But now when I access the api through it gives an error "Unclassified Authentication Failure. Error while accessing backend services for API key validation"

Comment: as of v1.6.0, I cannot find this option anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but I found that I also had to update the api-manager.xml file in conf, replacing references to carbon.local.ip with the hostname. This addressed the issue where the ip address was still used in the store. However, I still have an issue which appeared after changing the hostname where issuing and recreating tokens fails. I'd be curious if were/are seeing that issue(which I think is related)